# How to make page transition between Express views?

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, transition

I have simple [Express](http://expressjs.com/) website / application and I would like to make transition between views / pages.

So if I am on `/home` and click to `/about` page, **the view will fade out the** `/home` **and fade in the** `/about`. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need an `$.get` call to the url `/about` on put the content in your dom, like this exmaple:

```
// add click handler to about-link
$('a.about').on('click', function() {

    // call /about
    $.get('/about', function(data) {     

        // fadeout content block and empty page content
        $('.content').fadeOut().empty();

        // add data from /about to content and fadein
        $('.content').html(data).fadeIn();
    });
});
```